# Как адаптировать "Сортировочную станцию" под матрицы

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, математика, матрицы

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как модернизировать обычный алгоритм сортировочной станции, под парсинг матриц и дальнейших расчётов?

Comment: Ээээ... А что вы понимаете под синтаксическим разбором матриц? Приведите пример исходного текста, и объектов, которые хотелось бы получить в результате разбора.

Comment: @VladD det( 8 * [[5,2,3],[2,5,5],[8,7,6]] * [[2],[-3],[1]] ). det=это функция нахождения определителя

Comment: Ну, `det` и `8*` разбирается и так. Вам нужно по сути `[...]` как операция, возвращающая столбец. Ну так разбирайте её как функцию, вот и всё.

Comment: @VladD хорошо, а вот собственно как хронить матрицу, в общем postfix expression'е ?

Comment: Я бы завёл для этого новый тип узла — `ROW` или там `VECTOR`, в котором хранится последовательность значений. Соответственно матрица — это вектор векторов, в прямом соответствии с вашей записью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переделаю [алгоритм из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Жирным выделены добавленные части:

- Пока не все токены обработаны:

  - Прочитать токен.
  - Если токен — *число*, то добавить его в очередь вывода.
  - Если токен — *функция*, то поместить его в стек.
  - Если токен — *разделитель аргументов функции* (например запятая):

    - Пока токен на вершине стека не *открывающая скобка* **(круглая или квадратная)**, перекладывать операторы из стека в выходную очередь. Если в стеке не было *открывающей скобки*, то в выражении пропущен *разделитель аргументов функции* (запятая), либо пропущена *открывающая скобка*, **либо пропущена *открывающая квадратная скобка***.
  - Если токен — *оператор* `op1`, то:

    - Пока присутствует на вершине стека токен *оператор* `op2`, и

      - Либо *оператор* `op1` лево-ассоциативен и его приоритет меньше, чем у *оператора* `op2` либо равен,
      - или *оператор* `op1` право-ассоциативен и его приоритет меньше, чем у `op2`,

      переложить op2 из стека в выходную очередь;
  - положить `op1` в стек.
  - Если токен — *открывающая скобка* **(круглая или квадратная)**, то положить его в стек.
  - Если токен — *закрывающая скобка* **или *закрывающая квадратная скобка***:

    - Пока токен на вершине стека не является **парной** *открывающей скобкой* **(то есть для закрывающей круглой скобки открывающей круглой, а для квадратной — квадратной)**, перекладывать операторы из стека в выходную очередь.
    - Выкинуть *открывающую скобку* из стека, но не добавлять в очередь вывода.
    - **Если открывающая скобка была квадратной, добавить в очередь вывода токен `ROW`**
    - Если открывающая скобка была круглой, и токен на вершине стека — функция, добавить её в выходную очередь.
    - Если стек закончился до того, как был встречен токен *открывающая скобка* (парная), то в выражении пропущена скобка.
- Если больше не осталось токенов на входе:

  - Пока есть токены операторы в стеке:

    - Если токен оператор на вершине стека — скобка, то в выражении присутствует незакрытая скобка.
    - Переложить оператор из стека в выходную очередь.
- Конец.

Теперь у вас есть новая функция `ROW` со списком аргументов, которая должна создавать строку (вектор) аргументов в том виде, в котором вы его храните в программе.